# How to disable event notifications for group I'm not in?

Tags: steam

I used to be a part of the "Tomb Raider Multiplayer Madness" Steam Group. They have regular weekly events. I became annoyed with the event notifications, so I thought leaving the group would cease them. I left the group. I'm still getting event notifications from the group. How do I stop the event notifications?

Answer (score 15):

Apparently, with the new "Explore your Queue", when you choose to follow the game, it adds that game to your groups and it can only be removed through the community hub of that game.

Do not follow games if you do not want notifications from that game.

Answer (score 9):

In your friends list, there's two tabs - one for friends, another for groups. Click the groups tab, and you'll likely see the tomb raider group there. You can remove yourself from there.

If that doesn't work, go to the [Tomb Raider community hub](http://steamcommunity.com/app/203160). There should be an unfollow button on the page:

[image]

Between these two locations, you're guaranteed to never be notified of any Tomb Raider events ever again.

Comment: I am not following the group any longer on either of these tabs, yet I expect another event notification. It shows the green "Join Group" button for the group page. Is following different from joining?

Comment: Just updated my answer now that I'm at my desktop computer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I left the group but still getting notifications.

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for me. This stopped games from sending me constant weekly/monthly ‘event’ notifications, games I don't even play or remember buying.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your name on Steam and click "activity" in the dropdown menu. On the top of the next page, click "friend activity settings" and from there you should be able to turn off all the popup notifications you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

Open FRIENDS > CLICK SETTINGS (gear icon) Then you'll see **Group Events and Announcements** at the bottom of the list:

[image: Settings]

Comment: I think you mean 'Friends & Chat' - there is another 'Friends' button at the top which doesn't give access to Settings or Notifications.

Comment: this solved my problem, thank u

Answer (score 3):

You only need to open STEAM. Click "STEAM" in the top left corner, then click "Settings", this opens the setting window.  Now click "Friends" and near the bottom locate "For Group events and announcements" and uncheck "Display a notification".  This will stop the issue.

Comment: Can not find "friends" in settings.

Comment: Now you need to open up the Friends List and edit the settings there.

Answer (score 1):

**I found it!** As of 2020 Steam. Open Steam, click your Name under the bar:

[Store Library Community **Your Name**] (Takes you to "activity")

Then on the bottom right you'll see View Groups, and even Upcoming Events including the ones you are sick of seeing.

Click **View all X groups**.

Find whatever group won't stop spamming you with events and click **Leave Group**.