# How to disable steam in-game notifications?

Tags: steam

When I'm playing a game from Steam I get in-game notifications like "Game X announces a new update" and it is very distracting, and I can't seem to find a setting that will disable it...

How do disable these in-game "game announcement" notifications?

Comment: Just to be sure: you *only* want to disable the kind of notification you mentioned. You don't want to disable the Steam Overlay altogether. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203562/how-to-disable-event-notifications-for-group-im-not-in)  might help.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Steam friends list, and click the gear/settings icon near the top right.

In the friend list settings window, select Notifications on the left, and uncheck the"Show a notification" checkbox for the "Group events and announcements" row.

Comment: The notifications are game related not friend related.

Comment: It's still in that menu though

Comment: To clarify, when you click "follow" on a game's store page, it makes you join that game's official steam group. That's where the events and announcements are posted.